UMP test for Uniform$(- \theta, \theta)$
Let $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ be a random sample from a Uniform$(- \theta, \theta)$ distribution, where $(\theta > 0)$.
Derive the UMP test for testing the null hypothesis:
(a) $H_0$: $\theta = \theta_0$ $vs$ $H_1$: $\theta > \theta_0$
(b) $H_0$: $\theta = \theta_0$ $vs$ $H_1$: $\theta < \theta_0$
(c) $H_0$: $\theta = \theta_0$ $vs$ $H_1$: $\theta \neq \theta_0$
In each case, identify the test statistic and critical region.
I am not able to understand how to proceed, since in this case, I am not able to get MLR for complete sufficient statistics which is $max(|X_1|,....,|X_n|)$.
Can we take $|X|$ and then solve as we do for Uniform$(0, \theta)$ ?

consider $\max(\max (\bf X),-\min  (\bf X))$. This will give you the best estimation of $\theta$

@Seyhmus Isn't it same as saying max$(|X_1|, ...., |X_n|)$

@AnkitaGoyal yes true. My version only shows explicitely what is thought,

Yes, you can take $|X_1|, \ldots, |X_n|$ and solve the problem in the case $\text{Uniform}(0, \theta)$. In general, for problems which a sufficient statistic is available, you can transform the problem into the version using only sufficient statistics and consider only tests which is a function of the sufficient statistics.
Here is the somewhat length justification containing all details :
First of all, you can check easily that $|X|$ follows $\text{Uniform}(0, \theta)$ if $X$ follows $\text{Uniform}(-\theta, \theta)$.
Let us introduce some notation. Define $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ by setting $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (|x_1|, \ldots, |x_n|)$. Write $Y = (Y_1, \ldots, Y_n) = f(X) = (|X_1|, \ldots, |X_n|)$. Put $\Theta_0 = \{\theta_0\}$ ($\theta$ for null hypothesis) and $\Theta_1$ be as in one of the three alternative hypothesis you post. Fix $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and say you have already found $T(Y)$, the uniformly most powerful test of level $\alpha$ for the same problem but for sample $Y$ following $\text{Uniform}(0, \theta)$ distribution. We claim that $T(Y) = T(f(X))$ is still the uniformly most powerful test for the original problem you post. First of all, it still has level $\alpha$ because :
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} \mathbb{E}_{\theta} [T(f(X))] = 
\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} \mathbb{E}_{\theta} [T(Y)] \leqslant \alpha
\end{equation*}
Next, let $S(X)$ be any test of the original problem of level $\alpha$. Since $S(X)$ has the same powerful function as $\mathbb{E}[S(X) | f(X)]$ thanks to the fact that $f(X)$ is sufficient, we assume without loss of generality that $S(X)$ takes the format $S(Y) = S(f(X))$. Since $S$ has level $\alpha$ in the original problem, it has level $\alpha$ in the $Y$ problem by just writing out the definition. Since $S$ is of level $\alpha$ in the $Y$ problem, the uniformly most powerfulness of $T(Y)$ in the $Y$ problem shows that, for any $\theta \in \Theta_1$ :
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}_{\theta} [S(Y)] \leqslant \mathbb{E}_{\theta} [T(Y)]
= \mathbb{E}_{\theta} [T(f(X))]
\end{equation*}
This proves, by definition, that $T(f(X))$ is the uniformly most powerful test of the original problem.
The only thing left for you to do is therefore solve for $T(Y)$, but that is a standard problem with solution that can be found in any textbook.
